# Are touch and chmod write operations?

Tags: linux, unix, chmod

If a file system is in read-only mode, will I be able to perform `touch` and `chmod`?
When does an operation qualify as a read or write operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`touch` creates a zero byte file when called on a non-existent file.  And it updates file's metadata based on the arguments passed.  `chmod` does not change a file's data; it just changes the metadata contained in the file's inode.

However, the metadata itself is a part of the file system and hence it is a write operation.

In summary, both `touch` and `chmod` are write operations.  They can't be run on a read-only file system.

Comment: I didn't say `touch` doesn't change the inode.